# передача файла большого размера через сокет python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, сокет, python-3.7

имеется файл весом 1гб я передаю его через сокеты на локальном устройстве, скорость достигает 100 мегабайт/сек. а когда запускают сервер на другом устройстве в той же сети, используется wifi для обмена данными, то скорость всего 2 мегабайта/сек. как можно реализовать передачу в разы быстрее чем эти никчмные 2 мб/с по wifi сети?

код сервера:

```
import socket  
s = socket.socket() 

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 
socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  

s.bind(('localhost', 9090))  
s.listen(1)  
conn, addr = s.accept()  
op = open('test.img', 'wb') # 1gb
while 1:  
    data = conn.recv(1024)  
    if not data:  
        exit()  
    op.write(data)  
op.close()
```

код клиента:

```
import socket  
s = socket.socket() 

s.connect(('localhost', 9090))  
op = open('test.img', 'rb')  
while (data):  
    data = op.read(1024)  
    if not data:  
        exit()  
    s.send(data)  
op.close()  
s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19741196/7927226 -- судя по тому, что тут пишут, проблема в `recv`, может быть, что-то из ответов будет полезно

Comment: Вы не рассматривали вариант, что у вас wi-fi медленная дрянь?

Comment: `data.recv(1024)` — этот код вообще не должен работать, потому что `data` имеет тип `bytes`, а у `bytes` не существует метода `recv`

Comment: скорость скачки в браузере через wifi примерно 7 мегабайт/с тем не менее код работает

Comment: действительно в коде была ошибка conn.recv(1024)

Comment: Теперь в текущем варианте при передаче пропадают первые 2048 байт файла, потому что значение `data`, созданное перед циклом, никак не используется и просто выбрасывается (впрочем, к проблеме со скоростью это не относится)

Answer (score 1):

У меня получилось 10,6MB/s по вайфай (100 мегабитный провод, упираюсь в него).

передача:

```
import os
import socket  
s = socket.socket() 
s.connect(('192.168.117.33', 9090))
sf = s.fileno()
lf = os.open('/home/eri/Downloads/SNG7-FPBX-64bit-1904-2.iso', os.O_RDONLY)

while os.sendfile(sf,lf,None,1024*1024*10)>0:
  print('.', end='')
```

приём:

```
import os
import socket  
import io
s = socket.socket() 

s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, 
socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)  

s.bind(('0.0.0.0', 9090))  
s.listen(1)  
conn, addr = s.accept()

pp = open('test.img', 'wb')

buf = memoryview(bytearray(1024*1024*10))
nbytes = 1

while nbytes:
    toread=1024*1024*10  
    view = buf[:]
    while toread:
       nbytes = conn.recv_into(view, toread)
       view = view[nbytes:]
       toread -= nbytes
       if nbytes == 0 :
            buf=buf[:-toread]
            break

    pp.write(buf)
    print('.', end='')
```

тут в конце не очень уверен со вьюхами.